# What's the supremum of this?

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to know how to show that the supremum
$$\sup_S\frac{(x-y)^2 + (t-s)^2}{(|x-y|^2 + |t-s|)^{\epsilon}}$$
is less than infinity, where $0<\epsilon \leq 1$ and
$$S = \{ (x,t), (y,s) \in [0,2\pi] \times[0,T] \mid (x,t) \neq (y,s)\}$$
where $0 < T \leq 1$.
What can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 
\begin{align}
\frac{(x-y)^2+(t-s)^2}{((x-y)^2+|t-s|)^{\varepsilon}}&\leq ((x-y)^2+|t-s|)^{1-\varepsilon}+\frac{|t-s|(1+|t-s|)}{((x-y)^2+|t-s|)^{\varepsilon}}\\
&\leq ((x-y)^2+|t-s|)^{1-\varepsilon}+|t-s|^{1-\varepsilon}(1+T),
\end{align}
and using the fact that $s\mapsto x^s$ is increasing for $s\in (0,1)$, we get 
$$\sup_S\frac{(x-y)^2+(t-s)^2}{((x-y)^2+|t-s|)^{\varepsilon}}\leq (4\pi^2+T^2)^{1-\varepsilon}+(1+T)T^{1-\varepsilon}.$$